# the heat equation with solution-dependent coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I meet the problem

$$u_t(t,x)=\frac{A}{B-u}u_{xx}(t,x)$$

with the boundary conditions:

$$u(0,x)=B, x\in[0,H]$$ $$u(t,0)=u(t,H)=0, t>0$$ $$u(+\infty,x)=0$$

I have not any idea to start. Can you help me please.

Comment: This would be a good candidate for a Laplace tranform, however you may have a tricky inverse transform to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try.

Comment: Since this is nonlinear, and you’re considering an IVBP, there may not be an explicit solution anyways. Can you provide more background to the problem?